# Accessing class method inside interface in Java

Tags: java

```
public interface Counter{
    class Base1{
        protected int count1;
        public Base1(){
            count1=0;
        }
        @Override
        public void putCount(){
           System.out.println(count1);
        }
    }
}
```

How to access putCount() in interface's class method and count1 variable?

Comment: your code has compile time error, remove `@Override` first from `putCount()` method

Comment: This [link](http://way2java.com/java-lang/inner-classes-java-lang/class-inside-interface/) has a good explaination on how to access method from inner class inside interface.

Comment: Could someone explain why there is a benefit to putting a class inside an interface?

Comment: @bhspencer: If you have a datatype that is used as part of your interface definition, you *could* define it as an inner class. But if you like this kind of bundling, or if you prefer two separate (class) files is imho a matter of personal preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Counter.Base1 myBase1 = new Counter.Base1();
myBase1.putCount();
```

The concept is called inner class, if you want to find further information. As `count1` is protected, you cannot access it from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

**We tried to understand your query & this is what we got.**
**Plz check it**

```
public interface Counter{
    class Base1{
protected static int count1;
        public Pblm(){
            count1=0;
            }
        public static void putCount(){
           System.out.println(count1);
         }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example below show how to call method of class inside an interface.

```
interface Outer1 { 
    public abstract void show(); 
    class Inner1 { 
       public void display() { 
          System.out.println("Hello 1"); 
       } 
    }
}  

public class Test extends Outer1.Inner1 {
   public static void main(String args[]) { 
      Test t1 = new Test(); t1.display(); 
   } 
}
```

See more at: [link](http://way2java.com/java-lang/inner-classes-java-lang/class-inside-interface/#sthash.HkXxmngr.dpuf)